# Why does `1 && true` get a bool value `true`, but `0 && true` get a number `0`?

Tags: javascript

Why does `1 && true` get a bool value `true`, but `0 && true` get a number `0`?
I tested it in Chrome Console and Firebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `expr1 && expr2` will return `expr1` if it is false, otherwise it will return `expr2`.

Comment: `&&` is a binary operator, it only has two values to operate on. Chains of logical operators are multiple binary operators evaluated _one after another_.

Answer (score 4):

Because that is how logical operators in Javascript are [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to behave.

Additional reference: [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), page 83.

Answer (score 2):

The && operator is commonly called logical and. If the first operand is false, null, undefined, "" or the number 0 then it returns the first operand. Otherwise, it returns the second operand

Comment: or the number NaN as in `NaN || alert("NaN is falsey")`